# Migration of CONNECT BY LEVEL from ORACLE to POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql

I Need inputs on Migration of CONNECT BY LEVEL from Oracle to Postgres.

Source Code from Oracle:

```
SELECT LEVEL,AST_TXRBATCHID_SEQ.NEXTVAL  AS BATCH
from DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= '2';
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: you shouldn't compare numbers to strings. `level` returns a number, `'2'` is a string. That is really bad coding style.

Answer (score 1):

Use `generate_series` and `NEXTVAL()` function.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/470e6/10)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create sequence AST_TXRBATCHID_SEQ start with 1 increment by 1;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id,NEXTVAL('AST_TXRBATCHID_SEQ') AS BATCH
from generate_series(1,2) as id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/470e6/10/0)**:

```
| id | batch |
|----|-------|
|  1 |     2 |
|  2 |     3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be:

```
SELECT 1 AS level, nextval('ast_txrbatchid_seq') AS batch
UNION
SELECT 2, nextval('ast_txrbatchid_seq');
```